# I opened my Recycle bin, and Microsoft Security Essentials says 'Your computer was cleaned'. Has malicious software been run?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, virus, anti-virus

Suppose I had malicious software in my recycle bin, and I opened the bin just to look in it, could the malicious software be activated?

A week ago I installed a photo viewer and backup program for copying pictures from my phone to my computer. The program came from a professional looking company site. After installation, my virus scanner didn't say there's anything suspicious.

That program is the only thing I downloaded.  Now I had uninstalled the program, and I open my Recycle bin. The uninstaller has probably moved some files to the bin.  MSE says it had detected some malicious software in the bin, and showed me this message when I opened the bin:

[image]

Comment: You can try opening MSE and looking at the history or the quarantine to see what it found.

Comment: And yep, viewing the history list. It found a severe item!

Comment: Was this item related to the program you had installed/uninstalled?

Comment: I think so. It says the software is an installer that installs unwanted software to your computer.

Comment: "Detected threats are being cleaned" is NOT indicating threats were detected, but is informing you of what currents settings are set to, which would be to clean detected threats.  You indicated that the message was "your computer is being cleaned", submit a screenshot, with MSE displaying that message.  It also seems you have two different questions, one about how malware can be activated, another about MSE.  You should pick one they are not related.

Comment: The message is disappeared from screen (of course). But it really had detected an item that it didn't detect earlier. The picture in my question is from the internet, but the text and appearance is the same.